# Stored procedure to generate row_number functionality against desc id

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to auto generate a column (Order_no) for which I am using row_number functionality with concat function. I wanted to generate for (last row id +1) and insert for a new row. Right now using

```
select concat('MES', 1 + ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id)) as order_no 
from PM_Order
```

With this query, I am able to generate a new row of `order_no` as I wanted but when I try with

```
select top 1 id, concat('MES', 1+ ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id)) as order_no 
from PM_Order 
order by id desc
```

it just updates with existing last id and does not create a new id.

How can I write a stored procedure and generate the `order_no` for new id desc. Please provide some ideas.

Comment: why don't you use the `identity` ?

Comment: Paste some result set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Desc with row number. Like below

```
select top 1 id, concat('MES', 1+ ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id DESC)) as order_no 
from PM_Order
```